# Issue replacing input value in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, prototype

I did an example about **replacing the input value** when the row is deleted but is not working (this is not a static example).

```
<script src="./edit_files/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./edit_files/application.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div class="contact">
<table border="0"> 
  <tr>
    <td><select class="position_id" id="obj_client_contact_attributes__position_id" name="obj_client[contact_attributes][][position_id]"><option value="1" selected="selected">INTELIGENT</option><option value="2">OTHER</option></select></td>

      <td><input class="should_change_value" id="obj_client_contact_attributes__phone_mail" name="obj_client[contact_attributes][][phone_mail]"  type="text" value="cristianoronaldo@realmadrid.com"/></td>

    <td>        
      <a href="#" onclick="mark_for_destroy_contact(this,true); return false;">DELETE</a>
        <input id="obj_client_contact_attributes__id" name="obj_client[contact_attributes][][id]" type="hidden" value="16594"/>
        <input class="should_destroy" id="obj_client_contact_attributes__should_destroy" name="obj_client[contact_attributes][][should_destroy]" type="hidden"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>

<div class="contact">
<table border="0"> 
  <tr>
    <td><select class="position_id" id="obj_client_contact_attributes__position_id" name="obj_client[contact_attributes][][position_id]"><option value="1" selected="selected">INTELIGENT</option><option value="2">OTHER</option></select></td>

      <td><input class="should_change_value" id="obj_client_contact_attributes__phone_mail" name="obj_client[contact_attributes][][phone_mail]" type="text" value="ONLY THE INPUT WILL BE test@hotmail.com IF I CLICK ON DELETE"/></td>

    <td>        
      <a href="#" onclick="mark_for_destroy_contact(this,true); return false;">DELETE</a>
        <input id="obj_client_contact_attributes__id" name="obj_client[contact_attributes][][id]" type="hidden" value="16594"/>
        <input class="should_destroy" id="obj_client_contact_attributes__should_destroy" name="obj_client[contact_attributes][][should_destroy]" type="hidden"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Here is the application.js file:

```
function mark_for_destroy_contact(element,should_destroy,should_change_value) {
 var element_text = $(element).up('.contact').down('.position_id',0);
 element_text.className = 'position_id';
 element_text.value = '';

 if (should_destroy) {
   $(element).next('.should_destroy').value = 1;
 }

 $(element).up('.contact').hide();
}
```

I tried this code but only works if I remove the first row.

```
function mark_for_destroy_contact(element,should_destroy,should_change_value) {
  var element_text = $(element).up('.contact').down('.position_id',0);
  element_text.className = 'position_id';
  element_text.value = '';

  $('should_change_value').update("test@hotmail.com");

  if (should_destroy) {
   $(element).next('.should_destroy').value = 1;
  }
  $(element).up('.contact').hide();
}
```

[Here is the live example in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cmorales/p3y1ge2r/5/)

[Here is the example download on Github but is not replacing the input value correctly](https://github.com/sayayingod/REPLACING-VALUE-FROM-INPUT-WHEN-IS-DELETED)

Comment: Read very carefully in the [jQuery doc](https://api.jquery.com/next/) what `.next('.should_destroy')` actually does.  It looks at the next sibling element and returns something ONLY if that very next element matches the selector '.should_destroy'.  That is often not what people want or what people expect when they use it.  I can't tell from your code if this is your issue or not, but it is a common one.

Comment: Do you want to delete the entire row when you click on the delete link?

Comment: Yes, i did it that here https://github.com/sayayingod/REPLACING-VALUE-FROM-INPUT-WHEN-IS-DELETED/archive/master.zip but I don't only want to delete the row also I want to change the input value to test@hotmail.com on each row deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I got it, you want to change the input value when the row is deleted, so do this:

```
function mark_for_destroy_contact(element,should_destroy,should_change_value) {
   var element_text = $(element).up('.contact').down('.position_id',0);
   element_text.className = 'position_id';
   element_text.value = '';

   var element_text2 = $(element).up('.contact').down('.should_change_value',0);
   element_text2.className = 'should_change_value';
   element_text2.value = 'test@hotmail.com';   

   if (should_destroy) { $(element).next('.should_destroy').value = 1;}

   $(element).up('.contact').hide();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much..didn't know how to deal with this.